# Difference between XML and XMI?

Tags: xml, xmi

Can some one shed some light on the difference between XML and XMI?
Can XMI be used in place of XML?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The XML Metadata Interchange (XMI) is an Object Management Group (OMG) standard for exchanging metadata information via Extensible Markup Language (XML).

XMI integrates four industry standards:

```
XML - eXtensible Markup Language, a W3C standard. 
UML - Unified Modeling Language, an OMG modeling standard. 
MOF - Meta Object Facility, an OMG language for specifying metamodels. 
MOF Mapping to XMI
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Metadata_Interchange

So *XMI is a specific application of XML.*

Comment: can XMI be used in place of XML? That was my question.

Comment: And the question just lies within there. If XMI is an application of XML, you cannot use it instead of XML. XMI has a strict purpose, XML is a way of defining markup languages. It's like asking if you can interchange bricks and a house to do the same thing.

Comment: XML is used as a part of XMI, so if you're using XMI then you're using XML.

Comment: so, that means, when I am required to deliver an XML file, if my code created a file called filename.xmi, I am correct?

Comment: @zengr: All XMI files are XML, but not all XML files are XMI.

Comment: Hi @RobertHarvey!I have a question:As you mentioned `not all XML files are XMI` then what it is?

Comment: @user2019510 See my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

OK, let's try this again.

*No, you cannot use XMI in place of XML.*  XMI *is a specific use* of XML.

XMI can only be used to exchange metadata information in accordance with the OMG standard.  XMI is a specific application of XML.  XMI can only be used for XMI purposes.  XML, on the other hand, can be used for all XML applications, *including XMI.*

Comment: Is this a StackOverflow doppelganger?

Comment: Well, I already answered the question once.  Satisfactorily, I thought.

Comment: go it, one last question, any way to convert XMI to XML?!

Comment: you don't quite seem to understand that XML itself is meaningless. one uses XML to build his own markup, by providing rules like XMI did. XMI *IS* XML, just as sharks are fish. That does, however, not mean, that every fish functions as a shark. 

If you want to "convert" XMI to XML, just don't touch the file and you are done.

Comment: I got my answer anyway, #  For XML data use org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLResourceFactoryImpl - creates XML and For XMI data use org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIResourceFactoryImpl - creates XMI. I understand XMI is a subset of XML File, but they are different in functionality.

Comment: I hate to say it but you still haven't understood. XMI is NOT a subset of XML; it is an APPLICATION of XML. You will almost certainly have problems later if you don't manage to understand the distinction.

Comment: thank you @RobertHarvey,`XMI is a specific application of XML`
if possible, what is the other applications of XML ?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I didn't realize xmi in the list of xml application you provided ?

Comment: @user2019510: I don't understand your question. The Wikipedia list is probably not a complete list of XML standards, and XMI isn't just XML... See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

An XMI document is an XML document. An XML document is not necessarily an XMI document.

This is an XML document:

```
<myXml>
  <myTag> myContent </myTag>
</myXml>
```

but it is not an XMI document.

XMI is a specific XML dialect. It consists of a specific set of tags with specific syntax and semantics aimed at describing a model.