# BPMN with OCL or other Constraints Language

Tags: xml, uml, bpmn, ocl, xmi

I am looking for (the) BPMN definition in terms of [xmi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Metadata_Interchange) and complete [MOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-Object_Facility) files, also including [OCL (constraints)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Constraint_Language). Does this exist? I found only a couple of OCL-statements in the files.

In contrast to that, the `Superstructure.xmi` of the **UML** (see [www.omg.org/spec/UML](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/About-UML/)) contains plenty OCL-statements.

Comment: The question has been closed. Could you be more precise according the reason or give an example, please? What makes this thread better? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605146/difference-between-xml-and-xmi

Comment: Search, and research. ...
    Write a title that summarizes the specific problem. ...
    Introduce the problem before you post any code. ...
    Help others reproduce the problem. ...
    Include all relevant tags. ...
    Proof-read before posting! ...
    Post the question and respond to feedback.

Comment: I just edited some links and further explanations in and voted to reopen. Where do you take the `Superstructure.xmi` from?

Comment: e.g https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20100901/Superstructure.xmi but that is for UML 2.4.1 where the embedded OCL had hundreds if not thousands of syntax and semantic errors. https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20161101/UML.xmi for UML 2.5 has only four (reported) OCL errors.

Comment: Just add Ocelot here: https://github.com/Huixtocihuatl/OPEN-BPMN-OCL. May be it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The BMPN 2.0.2 (formal/2013-12-09) is based on XSD rather than UML technology so the best you can hope for is XPath. But it looks to be completely free of constraints to me.

Comment: Actually the BPMN meta model is defined as XSD _and_ as MOF model (which is a valid UML model). But I agree that neither of them contain constraints (probably because it was deemed sufficient to state constraints in plain English)